# Why does this connection sometimes closes (RESET) Flags: 0x014 (RST, ACK) TCP

Tags: wcf, networking, tcp, wireshark, handshake

We have an issue on the acceptance environment during a handshake process. External service tries to send some data and during handshake sometimes we reset the connection after timeout around 2 minutes. In the picture below you can see communication between two services our server IP ends with 11 and external service IP ends with 5.
[image: RST, ACK]

The strange thing is that is more than 50% it's working and when it's happened (they will try to send us data every hour and we reject each of them). In between, if we send data to them the next try from them will be successful (picture below). In this case, they use the server IP ends with .6.
[image: success]

Does someone have a clue what can be a problem here? We have tried to find something in our logs but nothing wasn't logged. Some help regarding additional logging will be appreciated (we tried with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-configure-network-tracing and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/diagnostics/tracing/configuring-tracing?redirectedfrom=MSDN). Our backed in written in C# WCF. The additional fact, when we try to send data to them we never have an issue, it's always working.

Comment: what is the problem? Is that the fact that after your server sends data, and then they try to send data to your server, you accept it without setting timeout RST? Can you be more clear. What was expected scenario?

Comment: Hi @dgrandm, thanks for the reply. The problem is when they try to send us some data sometimes we Reset the connection (red line in Wireshark) but we cannot find the root cause. Do you need anything else that can help?